# Retrofit 2 get java socket time out exception

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Write this code to retrofit service generator:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://ipaddress:9100/";
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            ;
    public static <S> S createService(
            Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

but i get the java socket time out error after 20 second,what happen?how can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: Check if you're able to get response from a rest client like postman.
Check if you're connected to the same network of your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed to add your OkHttpClient.Builder object in retrofit object: try this.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
    .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl("http://ip:9100/")
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

Comment: thanks,but how can use the this public static <S> S createService(
            Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }?

Comment: no need to call that method, just get Retrofit object after initialization then your done for initial setup. e.g. public static Retrofit getClient(){
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://ip:9100/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient )
                .build();

return retrofit;

}